# Copy pdf and fill it,publish for local server, MVC c#

Tags: c#, pdf

This code on my computer is working perfectly, but when i published it and push it to a server it doesn't work, and i have no idea why. Can somebody help me?

```
        [HttpGet]
        public FileStreamResult Pdfs(int protokolID, string fajl)
        {
        string pathF = path + @"\Formulari\" + fajl;
        string dime = exam[0].pID + "_" + exam[0].vlasnikImeIPreizme + "_" + exam[0].pacijentImeZ;

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path + @"\" + dime))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path + @"\" + dime);

        string newfile = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "_" + fajl;
        string pathnew = path + @"\" + dime + @"\" + newfile;

        if (String.Compare(fajl, "saglasnost za anesteziju.pdf") == 0)
        {
            SaglasnostZaAnesteziju(pathF, pathnew, exam[0]);
        }

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathnew, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        return File(fs, "application/pdf");
        }
```

This is a controller.

Function that i am calling.

```
        public void SaglasnostZaAnesteziju (string pathF, string newfile, PacijentVlasnik pv)
        {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pathF);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newfile,                         FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
        fields.SetField("TextField1[0]", pv.vlasnikImeIPreizme);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[1]", pv.vlasnikAdr);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[2]", pv.vlasnikTel);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[8]", pv.pacijentVrsta);
        fields.SetField("TextField4[0]", pv.pacijentRasa);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[9]", pv.pacijentPol);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[3]", pv.pacijentImeZ);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[5]", pv.pacijentDatumRodj.ToString("yyyy."));
        fields.SetField("TextField1[4]", pv.pID);
        stamper.Close();
        }
```

All paths and data is correct. i have no idea why it's not working when i publish my solution.

Comment: Can you get logs from the server, e.g. IIS logs or the event log, or a stack trace from a failing request? Although actually I'd guess the problem is the filesystem access. You might have to use the system temp directory rather than creating folders and files inside your IIS app, or you need to set filesystem permissions carefully if you're creating and caching files on demand. Are you in medium trust mode?

Comment: i was thinking the same, but i have pictures that are added and saved on local server, and that is working, and Directory creating. And all that is working, except this.

Comment: OK. You'll need to find some logs from a failing request then to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

it was just missing one line in function:

```
public void SaglasnostZaAnesteziju (string pathF, string newfile, PacijentVlasnik pv)
{
        var str = System.IO.File.CreateText(newfile);
        str.Close();
        System.IO.File.Copy(pathF, newfile, true);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pathF);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newfile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        fields.SetField("TextField1[0]", pv.vlasnikImeIPreizme);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[1]", pv.vlasnikAdr);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[2]", pv.vlasnikTel);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[8]", pv.pacijentVrsta);
        fields.SetField("TextField4[0]", pv.pacijentRasa);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[9]", pv.pacijentPol);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[3]", pv.pacijentImeZ);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[5]", pv.pacijentDatumRodj);
        fields.SetField("TextField1[4]", pv.brcip);

        stamper.Close();
    }
```

The problem was: that file must be first created and then we can do Copy.